# <a> tag not working when Html.ActionLink is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio, hyperlink

I'm just starting out with MVC and I need a div to become a link to another page. Whenever I make it a link using the  tag with href I get a Server Error in '/' Application message. But when I make a piece of text into a link using Html.ActionLink, it works flawlessly.

Here's my code for the div link that doesn't want to work:

```
<a href="../Home/Page1"> <div class = "col1"> Function 1 </div> </a>
```

Please help!

Comment: I have now noticed that this error occurs with any new view I try to create, the only time a link of any sort works is when I'm calling the About and Home pages, which are created by default in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u can use Url.action for address

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Page1", "Home")"><div class = "col1"> Function 1 </div></a>
```

Comment: Yes. Always try to avoid hard-coding links as much as possible. `Url.Action` and `Url.RouteUrl` can both be used as the href to a standard anchor tag. `Url.RouteUrl` works just like `Url.Action`, only it uses route names instead of Action/Controller.

Comment: Still getting same error, and Page1 is a view, Page1.cshtml, so not sure if that changes anything or not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the path, change this:

```
<a href="../Home/Page1">
```

to this:

```
<a href="/Home/Page1">
```

***BEAR IN MIND*** I'm assuming that `Page1` is an action.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT! Turns out I wasn't following the naming conventions of MVC, and "Page1" should have been called "Index", so the system was having a small heart attack whenever I tried to call the page. As for Url.Action() method, that actually solved the actual problem that I was looking to fix in the first place, so THANK YOU!!